# Swift- Reusable Framwork not working in higher version xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have create a simple reusable framwork and run that on XCode 9.4.1 and and seprate the .framwork file 
When I am using this framwork with XCode 10.1 there is an error coming like

**Module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.1 compiler: /Users/apple/Desktop/projectName/demo.framework/Modules/Demo.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule**

Is there  any way to use that previous framwork in my latest code, or any other suggestion. 
Should I need to compile that framwork on latest XCode 10.1, If yes, does this work on XCode 9.4.1 or lower version.

Comment: You just need to build your framework again with the new XCode version, then you can use it in your new project.

Comment: Means for every xcode I have to run every time my source code? This is not a solution for reusablity.

Comment: It depends on the swift version you used to build the framework, so you only need to re-compile your framework if you want to use it with a newer swift version. It doesn`t depend on the xcode version.